# Doesn't perform what I'm asking unless I click close (pygame)

Tags: python, loops, button, pygame, program-entry-point

the button clicked function doesn't run unless I click the top left exit button which won't close my game but instead, perform the task I am actually asking it to do. help?

```
def game_intro():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                for button in buttons:
                    if button[1].collidepoint(event.pos):
                        button[2] = HOVER_COLOR
                    else:
                        button[2] = BLACK

                        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        for text, rect, color in buttons:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)
            screen.blit(text, rect)

            pygame.display.flip() 


def button_clicked():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                print('test')

            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(60)

game_intro()
button_clicked
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `game_intro` function has an infinite loop, a `while True:`, that you only exit from in one place:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    return
```

So, until you quit, the function never returns.

Which means the rest of your code never runs.

---

There's an additional problem: after you quit and your function returns, you try to do more stuff, instead of quitting as the user asked you to.

---

And there's a third problem that hides the second one: you forgot to actually call `button_clicked()`; you just reference the function, `button_clicked`, which does nothing.

---

Anyway, what you probably want to do is get rid of the `button_clicked` at the top level, and add an `if` test to the main event loop that calls `button_clicked()` if the user clicks the button.

That design would be pretty weird. Normally, you want a game to have a single frame or event loop, not jump from one loop to another. But it wouldn't be illegal or anything, and it would do what you seem to want here.

---

While we're at it:

- If you *do* want two frame loops, you probably want to do the same `clock.tick(60)` in both of them, not just the second one.
- You probably only want to call `pygame.display.flip()` once, at the end of the blit loop, not every time inside the loop.

But these two problems will (at worst) cause flickering and excessive CPU usage, not actual broken behavior.

Comment: I'm new to pygame and i'm just following along tutorials. What would would a single frame or event loop look like and then how would I call the different functions under the event loop.

Comment: @CianMc Normally, you just call a function that does something (e.g., modifies some variables, creates some sprites, etc.) and then returns immediately to your frame loop. I don't know what tutorials you're following, but this is what almost all of them do. The only real exception is when you have "modal" functionality—e.g., what you do is so different between the menu, the game, and the highscore page that it makes sense for them to have completely separate loops—in which case you don't call a function from the frame loop, you return to some top-level code that runs the appropriate next loop.

Answer (score 0):

The button_clicked method is missing a set of brackets when it is called :)

```
game_intro()

button_clicked()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: oh haha didn't see that, problem is still occurring tho :\